# How to split vertically three-way tables using janitor and kable in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, janitor

When I knit these two tables they appear side by side.

What can I do to split them vertically, one for each group of `c`?

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(knitr)

df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
             b = c(3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
             c = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

```
df %>% tabyl(a, b, c) %>% 
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col")) %>%
  kable()
```

Comment: @RonakShah But I expected two table not side by side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `purrr::walk2` or `purrr::map` to call `kable` on each of the tabyls in the 3-way list.  You'll also need to put

````
 ```{r, results='asis'}
````

in the RMarkdown chunk header.

```
df %>% tabyl(a, b, c) %>% 
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col")) %>%
  walk2(names(.), ~ print(kable(.x, caption = .y)))
```

[image]

Other aspects of this problem are discussed in the GitHub issues for both the [janitor](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/issues/212) and [knitr](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1981) packages in the threads I linked.

Comment: This solution doesn't knit in html or pdf.

Comment: What happens when you try?  I just posted a screenshot of what it looks like when it successfully knits to HTML on my system.

Comment: Yes, that's also what I get. But the format is not what is normally expected when you use rmarkdown.

Comment: Ah yes of course.  See my updated answer.